# Mysql percentage of occurrences of a value from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, percentage

I have two tables, both have similar data including unique hostnames and varied domain names as well as operating systems. One has all of the hostnames and corresponding domain and operating system, the other has only hostnames and domain for devices that received updates. I have tried inner joins and where statements. I am a novice at code and end up with strange results.

I need to find the the percentage of occurrences of total hostnames within a unique domain based upon operating system and operating system role, i.e. Server, Workstation with a common name such as Winders 2012 Server, Winders 10, etc. The issue I am trying to solve is to find out how many devices by percentage within a particular domain have received special updates within specific role of operating system. I want to se how many servers are installed out of possible servers for a domain. See results desired.

Using MySQL 5.7.18, UTF8 charset

Table 1:

```
mysql> select Name,domain,OperatingSystem from ad_computers;
+-------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
| Name        | domain         | OperatingSystem                 |
+-------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
| NJ03DC01    | smallscomp.com | Winders Server 2008 R2 Standard |
| CORPDC01    | smallscomp.com | Winders Server 2008 R2 Standard |
| CORPWEB1    | anothercom.com | Winders Server 2008 Standard    |
| MN1FP1      | stupidsism.com | Winders Server 2008 Enterprise  |
| CORPFAS1    | stupidsism.com | Winders Server 2008 Standard    |
| CORPSOFTLIC | saturdayis.com | Winders Server 2012 R2          |
| NJFP1       | saturdayis.com | Winders Server 2008             |
| NY1FP2      | anothercom.com | Winders Server 2012 R2          |
| BOSPD-PC5   | anothercom.com | Winders 8.1 Professional        |
| NYPD-PCO4   | anothercom.com | Winders 8.1 Professional        |
| NYPD-SERV   | anothercom.com | Winders Server 2012 R2          |
| ODLPD-PCO8  | saturdayis.com | Winders 10 Enterprise           |  
+-------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Table 2:

```
mysql> select Name,domain from installed_soft;
+-------------+----------------+
| Name        | domain         |
+-------------+----------------+
| CORPDC01    | smallscomp.com | 
| CORPWEB1    | anothercom.com |
| MN1FP1      | stupidsism.com |
| CORPFAS1    | stupidsism.com |
| CORPSOFTLIC | saturdayis.com |
| NY1FP2      | anothercom.com |
| NYPD-PCO4   | anothercom.com |
| NYPD-SERV   | anothercom.com |
| ODLPD-PCO8  | saturdayis.com |
+-------------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Results Desired for Role type Server, i.e. - like '%Server%':

```
+----------+----------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------+
| OS Type  | domain         | TotalHostsPossible | TotalHostsInstld | PercentInstl |
+----------+----------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------+
| Server   | smallscomp.com | 2                  | 1                |  50          |     
| Server   | anothercom.com | 3                  | 2                |  67          |    
| Server   | stupidsism.com | 2                  | 2                |  100         |    
| Server   | saturdayis.com | 2                  | 1                |  50          |    
+----------+----------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------+
```

I have tried all kinds of things, and I do not think the code below is complete and may even be wrong. I tried an inner join too with similar results.

```
SELECT ad_computers.Domain,
       count(installed_soft.name) as TotHostInstld, 
       1.0 * COUNT(installed_soft.Name) / 
       (Select COUNT(distinct ad_computers.Name) 
        from ad_computers 
        where ad_computers.OperatingSystem like '%Server%') * 100 as PercentInstl
FROM ad_computers,installed_soft 
where ad_computers.OperatingSystem like '%Server%' 
  and ad_computers.name=installed_soft.name
GROUP BY domain;
```

Is there a way to do this? I don't care about performance or formatting as long as I get the data. Table 1 has about 50k records and Table 2 has about 3k records. My test query takes about 10s to run. I am usually good at figuring things out, but any help would be appreciated. (I am not a SQL braintrust, just a security guy trying to use SQL.)

Comment: from where u are calculating TotalHostsPossible

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
    SELECT ad_computers.Domain,COUNT(distinct ad_computers.Name) as TotalHostsPossible,count(installed_soft.name) as TotHostInstld,
 1.0 * COUNT(installed_soft.Name) / COUNT(distinct ad_computers.Name)*100 as PercentInstl
    FROM ad_computers inner join installed_soft 
    on ad_computers.name=installed_soft.name
    where ad_computers.OperatingSystem like '%Server%'
    GROUP BY domain;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT 
    IF(a.OperatingSystem like '%Server%' ,'Server','Workstation') as `OS Type`,
    a.domain,
    count(distinct a.name) as TotalHostsPossible,
    count(distinct b.name) as TotHostInstld, 
    count(distinct a.name) / count(distinct b.name) * 100 as PercentInstl
FROM ad_computers a
JOIN installed_soft b 
    ON a.name = b.name
where a.OperatingSystem like '%Server%' 
GROUP BY a.domain;
```